# How to add another image to my slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a slideshow and I would like to know how to add a third image. Here is my code: (by the way image 3 stated below is the image I would like to insert in too the slideshow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "http://jgsprograms.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/5/7/21578716/9889814_orig.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "http://jgsprograms.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/5/7/21578716/1421690233.png"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "http://jgsprograms.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/5/7/21578716/3920613_orig.jpg"

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" name="slide" id="slide"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<2)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new var and add a +1 to your counter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "http://jgsprograms.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/5/7/21578716/9889814_orig.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "http://jgsprograms.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/5/7/21578716/1421690233.png"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "http://jgsprograms.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/5/7/21578716/3920613_orig.jpg"
var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "http://jgsprograms.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/5/7/21578716/3920613_orig.jpg"

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" name="slide" id="slide"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<3)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
```

Also i do recommend using an array, will make your code much cleaner and understandable

Answer (score 0):

To the script scope add this same all others:

```
var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "http://jgsprograms.weebly.com/uploads/2/1/5/7/21578716/3920613_orig.jpg"
```

The code: `document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");`
will take it automaticly, because it's taking all your `Image()` objects in this HTML